# How to white-list specific routes of an application running on EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an application running on EKS. I used helm to provision it.

Now there is a requirement to white list three routes:

`/myservice/api/v1/servicename/route`

`/myservice/api/v1/servicename/route/routeA`

`/myservice/api/v1/servicename/route/routeB`

For two IPs:
153.197.13.192
153.197.13.207

Please note that the application should accept the traffic from anywhere, but white list the above three routes for only the above-mentioned IPs

Currently, my ingress looks like this:

```
spec:    
  ingressClassName: alb    
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service-name
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /servicename
        pathType: Prefix
```

I'm following this documentation, but it doesn't mention any white listing:
[Ingress annotation for EKS](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "153.197.13.192,153.197.13.207"
...
```